# Understanding code to flip a bmp image in C

Tags: c, bmp

I have an assignment to rotate and scale a bmp image in C. The code for flipping an image has been given to us to help us understand how it works, but I'm having a hard time doing so.

```
int flip (PIXEL *original, PIXEL **new, int rows, int cols) 
{
  int row, col;

  if ((rows <= 0) || (cols <= 0)) return -1;

  *new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));

  for (row=0; row < rows; row++)
    for (col=0; col < cols; col++) {
      PIXEL* o = original + row*cols + col;
      PIXEL* n = (*new) + row*cols + (cols-1-col);
      *n = *o;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My condolences.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Minor issue: For _large_ pictures, better to use `sizeof(PIXEL)*rows*cols`.  I assume your pictures are < 2G Pixels.

Answer (score 0):

```
int flip (PIXEL *original, PIXEL **new, int rows, int cols) 
{
  int row, col;

  if ((rows <= 0) || (cols <= 0)) return -1;

  *new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL)); // Allocate memory for the flipped image

  for (row=0; row < rows; row++)
    for (col=0; col < cols; col++) {
      PIXEL* o = original + row*cols + col;         // Get a pointer to pixel (row, col)
                                                    // in original image

      PIXEL* n = (*new) + row*cols + (cols-1-col);  // Get a pointer to pixel
                                                    // (row, cols - col -1) 
                                                    // in flipped image


      *n = *o;   // Copy pixel from original image to flipped image
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Assume you have a 2x2 image:

```
Loop 1: Original (0, 0) is copied to flipped (0, 1)
Loop 2: Original (0, 1) is copied to flipped (0, 0)
Loop 3: Original (1, 0) is copied to flipped (1, 1)
Loop 4: Original (1, 1) is copied to flipped (1, 0)
```